# Show bootstrap modal with custom title using React JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Hi all I have my working code here in local it is working fine what all I need is I need to assign custom text, here is the code pen for the same
https://codepen.io/dorababumeka/pen/bLeGrd
I am getting a warning as follows, I also want to hide this warning

```
$(this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()).modal();
```

Here is what I am getting in my local when I execute the same, I need to pass the user information to that modal instead of default values
[image]

Comment: What is the react version?`this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()` deprecated for version older than 0.14+

Comment: latest version of react I am using

Answer (score 1):

Since React v0.14, the `getDOMNode()` function has been deprecated and removed. Your code should instead be using the [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) method, something like this:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
    handleClick(i) {
      const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.modal);
      $(element).modal();
    }

//etc...
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQXPJX (note I have also had to add the Bootstrap JS library to get it working, but I assume you already have this in your local code)

Comment: Hi David how can I pass the content to the modal, like name and company